# Can I split a text file based on a pattern search?

Tags: awk, vim, grep

I have a text file, and i want to split this file by removing lines that contain specific words. For example:

```
remove those lines containing the word 'fish' from the file and output them into fish.txt

remove those lines containing the word 'cat' from the file and output them into cat.txt
```

...

Can this be done conveniently in vim, grep or some other simple ways? It doesn't have to be done in one flow, if complex. For each pattern, it can be done one at a time.

Comment: and what if a line contains both words?

Comment: I would say it's a catfish then

Comment: I am stunned that this got a single answer never mind 6 answers!!! It has neither sample input, nor expected output, nor any attempt at solving it from the OP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use this Vim function:

```
function! DeleteWord()
  let word=input("word to delete: ")
  let file=word.".txt"
  redraw
  silent! exe 'g/\<'.word.'\>/.w! >> '.file.' | d'
  echo "wrote to file ".file
endfunction
nnoremap <c-y> :call DeleteWord()<cr>
```

This can be called with  `Ctrl+y`. More info in the help pages of [`:w_a`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/editing.html#:w_a), [`:.`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/cmdline.html#:.) and [`:g`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/repeat.html#:g).

Comment: you can save and restore the z register with lets

Comment: I decided to avoid registers after looking at your answer, I think that `write >> ` is  better than my original approach.

Answer (score 2):

`awk` solution (assuming a line can contain `fish` or `cat`, not both):

Sample `input.txt` contents:

```
some text1
fish 1
some text 2
text cat 1
some text 3
some text 4
text fish 2
testx cat 2 cat 3
text text text
text ---- fish 3 ----
*** text ***
```

---

```
awk '/fish|cat/{ print > ($0~/fish/? "fish" : "cat")".txt"; next}1' input.txt > /tmp/_fc.txt \
&& mv /tmp/_fc.txt input.txt
```

Results:

```
$ cat input.txt
some text1
some text 2
some text 3
some text 4
text text text
*** text ***
```

---

```
$ cat fish.txt
fish 1
text fish 2
text ---- fish 3 ----
```

---

```
$ cat cat.txt
text cat 1
testx cat 2 cat 3
```

Answer (score 1):

With `gnu awk` you can do this

```
awk 'match($0,/(cat|dog|fish)/,a) {print >a[1]".txt";next} {print >"rest.txt"}' file
```

It will then use capture group `#1` as the file name.  You can ass as many word you like and a new file is been created for every word in the group, if its match. Then the rest is printed to `rest.txt`

This will also work with regex. More complicated expression could be used.
It will break if there are more than one trigger word on the same line.

---

Same `awk`version as RomanPerekhrest, but some more easy to read and simpler to expand.

```
awk '/fish/ {print > "fish.txt"; next} /cat/ {print > "cat.txt"; next} /dog/ {print > "dog.txt"; next} 1' input.txt > /
/tmp/_fc.txt > && mv /tmp/_fc.txt input.txt
```

Even better formatting:

```
awk '
    /fish/ {print > "fish.txt"; next} 
    /cat/ {print > "cat.txt"; next} 
    /dog/ {print > "dog.txt"; next} 
    1' input.txt > /tmp/_fc.txt \
&& mv /tmp/_fc.txt input.txt
```

Comment: good solution, please consider the case when cat and dog appear on the same line (omit the `next`).

Comment: @DudiBoy Not sure if OP will have trigger word more than once on the same line, he can comment this if needed.  Also added a gnu awk version.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to expand @Jotne to more general case, providing the list of words as input to the script.

Again with an `awk` script.

`script.awk` :

```
BEGIN {split(wordsList, words);} # get all the words into an array
{
    foundWord = 0;
    for (i in words) { # for each word
        if (match($0, words[i])) { # if found a word in input line
            print $0 > words[i]"s.txt"; # redirect input line to coresponding output file
            foundWord++; # mark word as found
        }
    }
}
(foundWord == 0) # output unmarked words
```

Script execution with words list given from `$list` varaible:

```
list="cat dog lion fly"
awk -v wordsList="$list" -f script.awk input.txt > input.cleared.txt
```

Cleared/cleaned `input.txt` is provided in `input.cleared.txt`

Answer (score 0):

Since grep comes from vi(m)’s `:g/re/p` command, answers using both:

From vim:

```
:global/\<word\>/.write! >>word.txt | delete
...
```

Grep:

```
grep 'word' > word.txt
...
grep -v 'words|to|delete' file > remaining
```

The `\v` is very-magic mode; the `-v` inverts matches.

Comment: We can abbreviate the command: `:g/\<dog\>/ .w! >> dog.txt | d` the dot is needed to indicate that only the current lines with the pattern will be added to dog.txt.

Comment: @SergioAraujo I’m well aware of the abbreviations—in scripts and SE answers (particularly [vi.se]), I prefer to write the full command for clarity. Learners and future readers gain nothing from obscurity. Good tip on the range though I had forgotten that.